# onmouseover="window.location=this.href" what code to make link opening on new tab

Tags: html, href, onmouseover

I have code what make some text-link opening when the mouse point to the link

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onmouseover="window.location=this.href">example</a>
```

what code to make this mouseover open new tab, if just code like that, it will open in the same tab.

Comment: Whether the browser opens a new tab or a new window is a user setting, so you will have no control over that. I realise this might be taking your question too literally, but fyi anyway.

Answer (score 1):

From a usability perspective this seems like a bad idea to open a new tab on mouse over.

Is there a reason you can open the link on click and use target="_blank" to open in a new tab?

For example:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">example</a>
```

Comment: didn't work, i mean code in the quote of onmouseover, it must change into some code, but i dont know that code

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example, does this do what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

To open a hyperlink 'on mouse over' use the HTML attribute:

```
onmouseover
```

'onmouseover' captures the moment that a cursor crosses the boundary of an element, moving from outside to inside the element to which the attribute is applied.

You will also need to use the:

```
window.open
```

JavaScript method.

Combine the two into a hyperlink and you get the following:

```
<a href="http://www.giancarlocolfer.com/" onmouseover="window.open(this.href, 'child')">This hyperlink to Web Design CT opens via onmouseover</a>
```

Reference, Code Sample, and Live Demo: [How to open a hyperlink 'on mouse over'](http://www.giancarlocolfer.com/blog/open-a-hyperlink-on-mouse-over/70/)